# Switching scenes error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a little game but when the app switches to the game scene (when pressing the restart button), than this game scene won't load correctly. It'll give an error: thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0). The whole game works fine in the beginning (if I didn't died yet) but when I die I'll go to another scene with a restart button and once this restart button is pressed I'll go again to the game. I won't even get the right background etc.

Code:

Game Scene (in this part the error will happen)

```
    func enemySpawn() {

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")

    let minValue = self.size.width / 8
    let maxValue = self.size.width - 150

    let spawnPoint = UInt32(maxValue - minValue) // HERE IS THE ERROR

    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.enemy
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.bullet
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    let action = SKAction.moveTo(y: -70, duration: TimeInterval(enemyMoveSpeed))
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    enemy.run(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

    self.addChild(enemy)
}
```

This is the restart scene:

```
var restartButton : UIButton!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    restartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 30))
    restartButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 7)

    restartButton.setTitle("Play Again", for: UIControlState.normal)
    restartButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
    restartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StartViewController.restart), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.view?.addSubview(restartButton)
}

func restart() {
    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.3))
    restartButton.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I hope someone will be able to help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you face the same issue on a real device?

Comment: I can't test it right now because I have reached the max 10 app ID limit in 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal impression is that you get the error from the previous (disposed scene.), but I might be wrong...

```
let nextScene = GameScene(size: self.scene.size)
        nextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

        self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

I would pass size to the GameScene, instead of default constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but I'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: You were right! I had to change this in all scenes!